# How can I fix a Node.js http post request or handle errors to more efficiently debug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

This example lacks some context, I know. But this request returns this error:

```
TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object
```

I think it is because of the of what is being based to the `data` field but I can't be sure. This api returns JSON, so I don't see the response as being the problem. What I am most concerned with is better error handling in Node. I could fix this a lot quicker if I knew exactly what the culprit was for the error. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Program.prototype.produceSomething = function(){
      const headers = {
        'Authorization': 'API_KEY',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
      const options = {
          url: 'SOME_API',
          path: 'SOME_PATH',
          method: 'POST',
          data: 'dataString',
          headers: headers,
      };
      let body = "";
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        let request = https.request(options,
          function(response){
            response.on('data', function(data){
              body += data;
            })
            response.on('end', function(){
              body = JSON.stringify(body)
              resolve(body);
            })
          })
          request.on('error', function(err){
            reject(err)
          })
      })
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get that error? Is `request` throwing it, or the endpoint that you are trying to post to?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is the request, yes. If I remove that block of code it throws an unhandled promise error.

Answer (score 0):

```
body += data
```

make sure data is string or buffer. You can cast to it if necessary.

For debugging, if you use alot of Promises, you can use the decorator pattern to log usefull things

Answer (score 0):

Since `options.data` is a string try setting the `Content-Type` in the headers to `text/html`.

If you want the content-type to be application/json, try setting `options.data` to a json object.